# C# WinForms ListView Item Count Change Event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, listview

Is there an event in Win Forms that can fire when the count of items in ListView change?  I tried Size and Text - oddly enough they "sorta" worked but not always...

Im trying to trigger a label to update with the count of the listview items as it changes without manually doing that in a hundred methods.

Comment: are your items being manually entered or are they from a bound data source ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are not using a bound datasource you can create a wrapper around the ListView Control and add a Method and an Event to fire off an event on adding an item to your ListView Collection.

**Custom ListView**

```
public class customListView : ListView
{
    public event EventHandler<CustomEventArgs> UpdateListViewCounts;
    public void UpdateList(string data)
    {
        // You may have to modify this depending on the
        // Complexity of your Items
        this.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(data));
        CustomEventArgs e = new CustomEventArgs(Items.Count);
        UpdateListViewCounts(this, e);
    }
}
public class CustomEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int _count;
    public CustomEventArgs(int count)
    {
        _count = count;
    }
    public int Count
    {
        get { return _count; }
    }
}
```

**Example Usuage**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        customListView1.UpdateListViewCounts+=customListView1_UpdateListViewCounts;
    }

    private void customListView1_UpdateListViewCounts(object sender, CustomEventArgs e)
    {
        //You can check for the originating Listview if 
        //you have multiple ones and want to implement
        //Multiple Labels
        label1.Text = e.Count.ToString();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        customListView1.UpdateList("Hello");
    }


}
```