# Any ListView Event which fires on change of Item count?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

Is there an event in Win Forms that can fire when the count of items in ListView change?

I got this link helpful a little but I cannot understand the answer as it is in c#.

[Reffered Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19192766/c-sharp-winforms-listview-item-count-change-event)

The answer in the link says about making some private function I guess..

If there is any event available than it would be more helpful than making a function or something.

Any help is greatfully accepted..

Comment: Where do you add/remove items of list view? monitor count of items there.

Comment: Through a textbox or/and checkbox... @RezaAghaei

Comment: Put the logic of add/remove in specific methods and write the codes there. (the codes that check count of items and perform what you need)

Comment: `Through a textbox or/and checkbox` no, that is how the user interacts with your code/app.  Where your code adds items, introduce a counter or whatever there.

Comment: actually I am making a listview by inheriting its windows properties and changing to what I want like done in the link for textbox, well I'll try to create method in that and inform you later... [LINK] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16134227/vb-net-class-to-change-textbox-backcolor-dynamically/)

Comment: As another option you can inherit from ListView and override WndProc and raise a custom ItemsCountChanged event when receiving LVM_INSERTITEM or LVM_DELETEITEM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

You can put the logic of add/remove in specific methods and write the codes there; the codes that you want to run when count of items changed.

**Option 2**

You can inherit from `ListView` and override `WndProc` and raise a custom `ItemsCountChanged` event when receiving [`LVM_INSERTITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930179.aspx), [`LVM_DELETEITEM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930145.aspx) and [`DELETEALLITEMS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms930143.aspx).

```
Public Class ListViewEx
    Inherits ListView
    Private Const LVM_FIRST As Integer = &H1000
    Private Const LVM_INSERTITEM As Integer = LVM_FIRST + 77
    Private Const LVM_DELETEITEM As Integer = LVM_FIRST + 8
    Private Const DELETEALLITEMS As Integer = LVM_FIRST + 9
    Public Event ItemsCountChanged As EventHandler
    Protected Overridable Sub OnItemsCountChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent ItemsCountChanged(Me, e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub WndProc(ByRef m As System.Windows.Forms.Message)
        MyBase.WndProc(m)
        Select Case m.Msg
            Case LVM_INSERTITEM, LVM_DELETEITEM, DELETEALLITEMS
                OnItemsCountChanged(EventArgs.Empty)
        End Select
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then you can subscribe for the event and do what you need:

```
Private Sub listView1_ItemsCountChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles listView1.ItemsCountChanged

    'Do stuff here
End Sub
```

**Note**

- You can enhance the above implementation and also create `ItemInserted` or `ItemDeleted` events.
- You can extract more information from mesages, for example you can find inserted or deleted item index and include in event args.
- For cases that you don't want to inherit from `ListView` you can do the same job using a `NativeWindow` and passing an existing `ListView` to the native window and assign list view handle to the window.

Comment: You are welcome :) you can kindly vote for answer by click on up arrow near the answer, also you can accept it by click on check mark near the answer.  [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

I know i'm late but this is by far the best solution:

```
Private Sub ListView1_Invalidated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ListView1.Invalidated

    nbr.Text = ListView1.Items.Count 'nbr.text is a Label Control

End Sub
```